# How do you create roles in Microsoft.Owin.Security in VisualStudio 2013 RC AccountController.cs - API documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In VisualStudio 2013 RC, using MVC5, in AccountController.cs, I had to modify the Login method to call WebSecurity.Login as I'm still using WebSecurity and Webmatrix to add users and user roles. I populate users and roles with WebSecurity and Webmatrix API using an Entity Framework 6 seed method. In my code examples WebSecurity.Login will handle a local user account, and CheckPasswordAndSignInAsync will handle a Google account login.

Should OWIN be a replacement for Webmatrix and the Websecurity API, if so what is Microsoft's OWIN API to create roles and users? Can't seem to find much documentation on OWIN  in MSDN. Has anyone created any sample code or aware of any docs that explain
how to use Microsofts' flavor of OWIN? Do you have to write your own code to populate
roles and users to the OWIN generated tables such as AspNetUsers and AspNetUserRoles?

This is login method:

public async Task Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Validate the password
            IdentityResult result = await IdentityManager.Authentication.CheckPasswordAndSignInAsync(AuthenticationManager, model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            //added this for roles to work
            else if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

This is signout method:

```
    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();

        WebSecurity.Logout();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a user, you need to write code like this:

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
// Add the Admin role to the user.
user.Roles.Add(new IdentityUserRole() { Role = new IdentityRole("Admin") });
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
// Code after successfully creating the user.
}
```